# Scatter plot with a range

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I have time series data, with percentile ranges.

So for each timestamp, i can have multiple intervals
eg. 20% to 21.1%, 42% to 48%,

I'm looking for a x-axis time series with y-axis to shade percentile time intervals. Any ideas which graph type would work ? thanks

I'm looking at few examples, but none of them are showing anything close. So wanted to get some ideas on which graph type can most likely solve this ?